# Delete many-to-many relationship throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

In a project using Entity Framework 6 as ORM (Code First), we have a many-to-many relationship between users and roles defined as this:

```
entity.HasMany(t => t.Roles)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UserRole");
                m.MapLeftKey("User_Id");
                m.MapRightKey("Role_Id");
            });
```

Now, the code used to remove a user from a role, in the end we call the SaveChanges of our context object:

```
RoleModel role = RoleModel role = m_UoW.Repository<RoleModel>().Query(r => r.Id ==     roleId).Include(r => r.Users).Select().First();

role.Users.Remove(role.Users.First(u => u.Id == userId));

m_UoW.SaveChanges();
```

But at SaveChanges a `InvalidOperationException` is thrown with the following message

> The ObjectStateEntry is a relationship entry. The current and original values of relationship entries cannot be modified.

And this StackTrace:

> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RelationshipEntry.GetUpdatableOriginalValues()
>
> at EFHooks.IaExtensions.b__2(ObjectStateEntry e, Int32 i)
>
> at EFHooks.IaExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5(ObjectStateEntry e)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at EFHooks.HookedDbContext.SaveChanges()
>
> at Repository.Pattern.Ef6.DataContext.SaveChanges()

Any ideas?

This is NOT a entity framework issue, i made a try with pure EF objects and all run as expected.

Comment: Hi, this should work without errors I've just tried out this code so most likely the problem originates from elswhere. Could you post the FindRole function and the other parts of the removal function?

Comment: Hi, i have replaced the FindRole method by inline code, this is all the code (call from a test method), also we are using the CodePlex Generic Unit of Work Framework.

Comment: What is `Select()` (without parameter)?

Comment: We are using the the EFHooks library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisoftInc.EFHooks/), this error is probably related.